# Error while sending a dropdown collection to a method accepting collection of Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics, extension-methods

I am trying to pass a collection of Dropdown controls as a parameter to a method which takes a collection of type Control as input. While executing I get the following error:

"Unable to cast object of type 'd__a3`1[System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.UI.Control]'."

Any idea why am I getting this?

My code:

```
private void Caller()
{
   IEnumerable<DropDownList> dropDownControlsInCurrentRow = currentRow.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>();
   SetControlsVisibility(dropDownControlsInCurrentRow, false);
}

private void SetControlsVisibility(IEnumerable<Control> controlCollection, bool visibilityFlag)
{
   foreach (ctrl in controlCollection) {
         ctrl.Visible = visibilityFlag;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the `OfType` method yours or the framework's? If it's yours, could you put up the code for that? If it's from the framework, what is the type of `currentRow`?

Comment: ^^ Its the IEnumerable extension method (in-built). currentRow is of GridViewRow type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
IEnumerable<Control> dropDownControlsInCurrentRow;
```

instead of

```
IEnumerable<DropDownList> dropDownControlsInCurrentRow;
```

Comment: ^^ I accepted this as answer because it gave me the quick, needed solution.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 4.0 the above code would work due to contravariance of T in IEnumerable.

In C# 3.5 and below you need to add an additional dropDownControlsInCurrentRow.Cast()

See this link [on contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) for more info